# RDP Session Utilizing Connections from Multiple NICs on Local Computer

Tags: remote-desktop, network-adapter, sql-server

I apologize if this sounds complicated.

We've recently setup a RDS for users to utilize an application that queries a SQL Database Server for security cameras setup at a manufacturing plant (located in a different country).

Traditionally, the users used this application locally on their computer, and would connect these cameras to the computer through the use of a second NIC on their computers, and from there, users would send a query to the SQL Database from the application (it administers MAC Addresses to the cameras). Unfortunately, the site-to-site VPNs don't work well with SQL queries, so we're trying to setup an RDS that should be able to make the SQL queires significantly faster.

NOW, the actual issue at hand is that since the cameras aren't just connected with USB, but instead, the second NIC (network cable) We don't know how to allow the RDP session to allow connection of the second NIC running from the local computer to show the connection in the application.

Is there a way to allow an RDP session recognize the second NIC/connections from the second NIC?